# Adding Unique ID/Name and Event Handling to Drawn Rectangles on PictureBox

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Template Editor program(C#/WinForms/VS2015) where I need to add rectangles to a picturebox and know the X,Y,Width, Height and a unique name for each one.

The Unique Name is the part I cannot figure out as it seems rectangles cannot have assigned names.

The rectangles should be draggable within the boundaries of the picture box and the editor should be able to add/remove, rotate, and increase/decrease size of each rectangle.

I believe I can figure most of it out once I know how to reference each instance of a rectangle.

I actually built the above functions before but using Buttons. I found out later that you cannot rotate a control so I guess back to square one. :)

Thank you

Comment: Maybe a new class with Name and Rectangle properties...

Comment: I will definitely try that tonight and update here how it goes. Thank you!